# I am trying to parse this string and get the last word

Tags: java, arrays, parsing

Is there something I am doing wrong here? When printed I get "*" and I need to get "-32". I am parsing each individual word and returning the last word.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(stringParse("3 - 5 * 2 / -32"));

}

public static String stringParse(String string) {
    String[] word = new String[countWords(string)];
    string = string + " ";
    for (int i = 0; i <= countWords(string); i++) {
        int space = string.indexOf(" ");
        word[i] = string.substring(0, space);
        string = string.substring(space+1);
    }
    return word[countWords(string)];
}


public static int countWords(String string) {
    int wordCount = 0;
    if (string.length() != 0) {
        wordCount = 1;  
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= string.length()-1; i++){
        if (string.substring(i,i+1).equals(" ")) {
            wordCount++;
        }
    }
    return wordCount;
}
```

Comment: Please explain why you think your code should print -32. Walk us through it.

Comment: Better yet, step through the code yourself in a debugger, examining the values of variables as you go (Eclipse, Intellij, NetBeans, etc).  You should be able to find the problem in a few minutes.  This is a skill worth developing.

Comment: Why do you call count words three times? It's an expensive function, and your code would break if it did in fact change value. BTW think about how you come make the code more effiecient.  If you can use String.indexOf why not use `string.substring(string.lastIndexOf(' ')+1)` to get the last word.

Comment: Don't deface your question, please. Rolled back.

Answer (score 2):

You could instead split the string by white space using "\\s+" and return the last element of that array. This will return the last word.

```
public static String stringParse(String s){
    return s.split("\\s+")[s.split("\\s+").length-1];
}
```

Comment: It would be better to store the result of split rather than calling split twice to get the length.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use regular expressions too :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(stringParse("3 - 5 * 2 / -32"));

}

public static String stringParse(String string) {
    String found = null;
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\s((\\W?)\\w+)$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
            .matcher(string);
    while (m.find()) {found = m.group();}
    return found;
}
```